# Google Maps Points do not appear until low zoom levels

Tags: javascript, perl, google-maps, kml

I'm working on a (Perl) program that uses the Google Maps API and a KML file to pull data from a database that creates points on the map. I have that much done, but the points only appear after I zoom pretty much all the way in, to a zoom level where only one point is showing.

The default zoom only shows my small city (3-5 miles) so I thought all the points would be able to show. Does anybody know how to get all of the points to show up at city-wide level as opposed to only showing up when zoomed all the way in?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Added a JavaScript tag because I've seen a lot of work done with Google Maps using JS, and considering the problem really isn't language-specific, I figured some of those developers might be able to offer some insight.

Comment: I'm working with him and just wanted to clarify that the perl only builds the xml from the DB and the Javascript within an HTML page does all the actual Google Maps interaction.

Also, the issue is not the default zoom level. The problem is that we can not see our markers at a zoom level that allows us to see the entire town at once.

Comment: r u using any library for plotting markers on map? eg Styled marker, or cluster markers etc..

Comment: Provide a minimal program that exhibits the problem. Your textual description is much too fuzzy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to incorporate the [`<Lod>`](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#lod) tag in your KML, which is child of a `<Region>`. You can define this once per placemark you get from your DB. or only once per query (defined by minLat, maxLat, minLong, maxLong). In the first case the LodPixels is a constant whereas in the latter case you must calculate it as a function of the region size. It sure works in Google Earth and may work as well in Maps. Look [here](http://dauda.at/locator/) to see it work in Earth API (JS)

```
....
<Region>
    <LatLonAltBox>
        <north>###</north>
        <south>###</south>
        <east>###</east>
        <west>###</west>
        <minAltitude>###</minAltitude>
        <maxAltitude>###</maxAltitude>
    </LatLonAltBox>
    <Lod>
        <minLodPixels>###</minLodPixels>
        <maxLodPixels>###</maxLodPixels>
        <minFadeExtent>###</minFadeExtent>
        <maxFadeExtent>###</maxFadeExtent>
    </Lod>
</Region>
....
```